# Gpj installation error in Linux

Tags: java, installation, javacard

i am new to java card development. i want to write java applet and create .cap file to the smart card.so  i read https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/JavaCard this article and i in download the gpj-20120310.zip and try to install that one in the Linux flat form.when i try to install using read readMe file when i entered java -jar gpj.jar command it gives **java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: PC/SC, provider: SunPCSC, class: sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC$Factory** Error.Can anyone tell me what is the wrong..

Thanks
SSV

Comment: What is your java JDK/JRE version? Check using java -version

Comment: OpenJDK or the version from Oracle?